# Routing Expres.js + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Prompt how to organize a diversion , that is , there is a file app.js it appeal to the base after the success should be redirected to '/messanger' who is in the routers in the file index.js

APP.js

```
app.post('/validation', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
    connection.query('SELECT `id`, `nickname`, `images` FROM `users` WHERE email="'+req.body.email+'" AND pass="'+req.body.pass+'"', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if(rows.length > 0){
            console.log("this");
           res.redirect('/messanger');
        } else {
            res.send({data: false});
        }
        res.end(); 
    });
});
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Messanger' });
});

router.get('/messanger', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('messanger', { title: 'Messanger' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: After a successful request to the database I need to organize a redirect to the page '/messanger'

Comment: Your code looks good. Why is the /validation route in app.js while the others in routes/index.js ?

Comment: You can use [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) to create a redirect, like you do in your code.

Changing the Express route halfway through is not something you should do. If that is what you're looking for, you should read up on [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) functionality.

Comment: That is my architecture is not correct? res.redirect - not work...